# Proving $H$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppose $H$ is the only subgroup of order $o(H)$ in the finite group $G$. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97054/suppose-h-is-the-only-subgroup-of-order-oh-in-the-finite-group-g-prove)

I have to solve the following problem. It's an exercise from Herstein's Topics in Algebra book.

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $o(H)$. Then prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Any hints?

Comment: Is there concrete examples for such groups ?

Comment: Why do you make a question if it is written "your answer"? And what do you mean "concrete examples for such groups"? *What* groups do you mean?

Comment: In the abelian case, take the cyclic group of order 4, which has only one subgroup of order 2. The symmetric group on three letters $S_3$ is the smallest non-abelian example. $H$ would be the alternating subgroup here, $A_3$.

Comment: @Mohamed: hmm, this raises possibly the question: what if $G$ is a finite group with the property that *all of its proper* subgroups $H$ have a unique order? Well, then $G$ must be *cyclic*. Proof (sketch): every p-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal and hence $G$ is nilpotent. So we can assume that $G$ is a p-group for some prime p. Note that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial and hence by induction $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, whence $G$ is abelian. If $G$ would not be cyclic then we can spit of a non-trivial direct factor of $G$, giving rise to two different subgroups of order p. Contradiction.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint.** If $g\in G$, how many elements does $gHg^{-1}$ have?

Comment: Although this may be clear, one should also show that $gHg^{-1}$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$ but I forget why the cardinality of $gHg^{-1}$ must equal the cardinality of the subgroup above. Why is it that $|gHg^{-1}| < |H|$ cannot happen?

Comment: $gHg^{-1}$ contains the identity, is closed, and is closed under taking inverses, so is a subgroup (it is an instructive exercise to check these facts). It is also an instructive exercise to check that the clear candidate for a bijection between $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ is indeed a bijection.

Comment: @math-visitor, since in the question $G$ is a finite group, it's enough to note $gxg^{-1}=gyg^{-1}$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but this is true for any group...

Comment: @theron: Great and enough Hint. +1

Comment: @Belgi I think Gerry meant that since $\,G\,$ is a finite group (set) then it is enough to check the map is $\,1-1\,$ in order for it to be also onto.

Comment: @Belgi, what DonAntonio said. I was answering the question math-visitor raised in his/her comment --- note that I directed my comment specifically to math-visitor.

Comment: @math-visitor: Both issues can be taken care of at the same time by noting that $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an invertible homomorphism from $G$ to itself: homomorphism since $(gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1}) = g(xy)g^{-1}$, and invertible because $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ is the inverse map.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a∈G$, the set $a^{−1}Ha$ is also a subgroup of $G$ ($∵$ If $H$ is a subgroup of$G$, then $x^{−1}Hx$ is also a subgroup of $G $ for$x∈G$. Also if $$H=\{e,h_{1},...,h_k\}$$ then$$ a^{−1}Ha=\{e,a^{−1}h_1a,...,a^{−1}h_ka\}$$ and these are all distinct elements of $a^{−1}Ha$, i.e. $o(H)=o(a^{−1}Ha)$. But if $H$ is the only subgroup of a given order. Hence $a^{−1}Ha=H$. In other words $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

@theron: $H$ is even a *characteristic* subgroup: it is invariant under any automorphism of $G$. Can you see why? The normality comes from the so-called *inner automorphisms*, that is conjugation by any element $g \in G$. 
Observe that the same holds true if your $H$ is the only subgroup of $index[G:H]$.