# If $G$ has exactly one subgroup $H$ of order $k$, prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

I am doing a presentation in my class, and I have to write the proof to this theorem. Could someone please verify whether it is correct or not? It is based on (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156008)'s proof.

> If $G$ has exactly one subgroup $H$ of order $k$, prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

**Proof:** Let $H=\left \{ e,h_{1},h_{2},...,h_{k-1} \right \}\leq G$. Then $|H|=k$.

*Claim:* The set $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ghg^{-1}:g\in G  \right \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

*Proof:* (one-step subgroup test)

Non-empty: Since $H\leq G$, $e\in H$. Then $geg^{-1}=gg^{-1}=e\in gHg^{-1}$. Therefore, $gHg^{-1}\neq \varnothing$.

Closure Inverse: Let $gh_{1}g^{-1},gh_{2}g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$. Then $(gh_{1}g^{-1})(gh_{2}g^{-1})^{-1}=gh_{1}g^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}g^{-1}$ (since $G$ and $H$ have inverses) $=g(h_{1}h_{2})g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$ (since $H$ is a subgroup hence a group) $\square$

Then $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ e,gh_{1}g^{-1},gh_{2}g^{-1},...,gh_{k-1}g^{-1} \right \}$ and so $|gHg^{-1}|=k$. Since $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$, $H=gHg^{-1}$. Therefore, $H$ is normal in $G$. $\square$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof has a couple of glitches.

> (Closure) Let $gh_1g^{-1},gh_2g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$. Then
>   $$
> (gh_1g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1})^{-1}=
> gh_1g^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1}h_2^{-1}g^{-1}=
> g(h_1h_2^{-1})g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}
> $$
>   because $H$ is a subgroup.

You have $h_2$ instead of $h_2^{-1}$. Besides, the parenthetical remarks are irrelevant: you're working in a group using known properties of the operations.

You haven't really proved that $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$, though, which is however easy.

---

There is a much simpler proof, however.

> For every $g\in G$, the map $\varphi_g\colon G\to G$, $\varphi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism, since
>   $$
> \varphi(x)\varphi(y)=(gxg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})=g(xy)g^{-1}=\varphi(xy)
> $$
>   Moreover $\varphi_g$ is bijective since $\varphi_{g^{-1}}$ is the inverse map of $\varphi_g$. Indeed
>   $$
> \varphi_{g^{-1}}(\varphi_g(x))=
> \varphi_{g^{-1}}(gxg^{-1})=g^{-1}gxg^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1}=x
> $$
>   and similarly $\varphi_g(\varphi_{g^{-1}}(x))=x$.

Thus $\varphi_g(H)=gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ (by homomorphism) having the same cardinality as $H$ (by bijectivity).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show me another way of doing it. :) Sorry for the glitches and missteps.

Comment: @numericalorange The map $\varphi_g$ is an *inner automorphism* of $G$. A really important tool to work on conjugation in groups. In general, using homomorphisms allows for shorter and insightful proofs. You can try and spot some similarities between the two approaches.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost there.

You're missing a step here:

> Then $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ e,gh_{1}g^{-1},gh_{2}g^{-1},...,gh_{k-1}g^{-1} \right \}$ and so $|gHg^{-1}|=k$.

You need to prove that the elements of $gHg^{-1}$ are distinct, but that's easy, since if $gh_ig^{-1}=gh_jg^{-1}$, then, cancelling the $g$ and the $g^{-1},$ we have $h_i=h_j$.

NB: Let $h_0=e$. Then $e=gh_0g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should put 'let $g\in G$' at the beginning. Also at line 2, it should be $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ghg^{-1}:h\in H  \right \}$. And at line -3, it should be $=g(h_{1}h_{2}^{-1})g^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$.