# Can a group have only $1$ subgroup of order $r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I found the following proposition in "Algebra - Michael Artin (P.59)":

> If a group $G$ has just one subgroup $H$ of order $r$, then that subgroup is normal.

I'm having a difficulty understanding how could a group have only $1$ subgroup of order $r$. Because we know from Lagrange's theorem:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G.$ The order of $H$ divides the order of $G$,

. . . that $r$ divides the order of $G$. Since the cosets of this subgroup partition $G$, and all have the same order $r$, therefore $G$ has many subgroups of order $r$. (Their number is equal to how many cosets we have.)

The proposition is easy to see if $r=|G|$ or $r=1$, but otherwise I don't see how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Among other things, any finite cyclic group has a unique subgroup of *any* order that divides the order of the whole group, and for any $n, S_n$ has a unique subgroup of order $\dfrac {n!}{2}$.

Comment: Why do you say "Therefore G has many subgroups of order r."?

Comment: @AnneBauval Because for example if we have a group of order 15, then there exists a subgroup H of order 3, and all the cosets of H will be of the same order as well, and they partition the group G. Therefore we have 5 subgroups of order 3.

Comment: They are cosets, not subgroups.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh I see where I went wrong. For some reason I was imagining the group G as being partitioned into subgroups, not cosets. Thank you!

Comment: For a proof of the theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2687352/104041).

Comment: Btw, the claim is provable even if you were right, which would simply mean that the assumption is false. A "classical" example is: "A nonabelian group of order $15$ has trivial center".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake made here is confusing cosets with subgroups. It's true we get many cosets of order $r$, but they are not necessarily subgroups. These cosets can be obtained by a subgroup $H$ as follows:

$$aH=\{ah \mid h\in H\}$$

but these cosets are not subgroups. (Because the identity is only in one of these cosets, namely $H$.)

Comment: In fact,  the identity is only in *one* coset, as the cosets partition.

Comment: @eggnog Absolutely right. I edited my answer in order not to confuse anyone who might have this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Though calling "order" cosets' size/cardinality reinforces somehow the OP's confusion...

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can.   In fact, cyclic groups have only one subgroup of each order dividing the order of the group. There are other examples.   $Q_8$, the quaternions,  have only one subgroup of order $2$.

For a subgroup $H$, only one coset is a subgroup (in general).  None of the other ones contain the identity,  for example.