# Is the hypothesis of $G$ being a finite group necessary in this exercise?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been trying to solve an exercise for my Algebra class and even found this question asked already:

[Suppose $H$ is the only subgroup of order $o(H)$ in the finite group $G$. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97054/suppose-h-is-the-only-subgroup-of-order-oh-in-the-finite-group-g-prove)

Although, is the finiteness hypothesis a must for this exercise?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Is $H$ required to be finite?  Or could $o(H)$ denote an infinite cardinal?

Comment: If $o(G)$ is finite, then so is $o(H)$, @GEdger.

Comment: Yes, but if not, I believe @GEdgar is wright... the new question I should solve is: is it possible to exist a group $G$ with infinite order but with one subgroup such as the $H$ above?

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the downvotes on this question. He's asking whether or not a hypothesis can be omitted, the answer to which could be as simple as a yes or a no with a citation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $|H|$. Fix an element $g \in G$ and let $K = gHg^{-1}$. Take $a,b \in K$. There exist $a' , b' \in H$ such that $a = ga'g^{-1}$ and $b = gb'g^{-1}$. Thus
$$
ab = ga'g^{-1} gb' g^{-1} = ga'b'g^{-1}
$$
which is an element of $K$ since $a'b' \in H$. Moreover, $e \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup, so
$$
e = geg^{-1} \in K
$$
Thus, we have shown $K \leq G$. Now, consider the maps
\begin{align}
f &: H \to K \\
&h \mapsto ghg^{-1} \\
g &: K \to H\\
&k \mapsto g^{-1}k g
\end{align}
I leave it to you to check that $g = f^{-1}$, which shows that $|H| = |K|$. By assumption, this means $H = K = gHg^{-1}$. Since $g \in G$ was arbitrary, this proves that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Notice that nowhere did we need to assume that $G$ was finite.

Comment: In fact, this proof works even if $H$ is an infinite cardinality! So we don't even need to assume that $H$ is finite.